# Q: Youtube Data Api v3 - How to Increase Quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to incease youtube data API V3 quota but their form "YouTube Data API Quota Extension Application" can not submit beacause it use captchar V1 (it needs using V2 but they didn't upgrade its in this form)
Pls help me, show me the way to send its. I found Youtube data API support but seem they are not existting.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to ask for the quota increase is [through the said form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/).

To deal with the recaptcha v2 upgrade, follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#what-happens-to-recaptcha-v1).

> If your site still uses reCAPTCHA v1, please upgrade to reCAPTCHA v2
>   immediately. We no longer support reCAPTCHA v1. Any calls to the v1
>   API will not work after March 31, 2018. Please [register a new
>   key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) and upgrade to v2.

Comment: Google didn't upgrade reCAPTCHA v1 to v2, won't they support youtube data api quota?